# How to add event handling to a control from a dynamically loaded OCX library in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ocx

In an Excel 2003 VBA project, I am using the TreeCtrl from MSCOMCTL.OCX. I add the control dynamically to a form in my application (see code below).

**I would like to handle the NodeClick event of the TreeCtrl.**

Since the control is added dynamically, just using TreeCtrl_NodeClick does not seem to work. Also I cannot use the WithEvents approch since it does not seem to work with types which are not known at compile time.

```
'Does not work. WithEvents probably only works on known data types that have events.
'private WithEvents treeCtrl As Object 

'This code adds the control to the form
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim treeCtrl As Object
    Set treeCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2", "MyTreeCtrl")
    'Does not work: AddHandler is not available in VBA.
    'AddHandler TreeCtrl.NodeClick, AddressOf UserForm1.MyTreeCtrl_NodeClick 
End Sub

'This is supposed to be the event handler but it does not get called.
Private Sub MyTreeCtrl_NodeClick(ByVal Node As Object) 
    MsgBox "Node clicked"
End Sub
```

Note that I need to load MSCOMCTL.OCX dynamically. I cannot put it as a static reference into my VBA project (since my project has to run in different versions of Excel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this response from MS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/isvvba/thread/7d24e065-2475-404a-946c-1ec108cf0006) "you cannot handle the events for a TreeView control added in runtime using Excel VBA", although there is a suggested workaround using VB6(!).

Is adding the control at design-time and then  hiding it until required an option?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. At least I know that I can stop searching now.
Regarding your question: I used to add the control during design-time, but then 64-bit Windows 7 came along and would not play nicely with a static reference to MSCOMCTL.OCX; details here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054371/excel-2003-on-64-bit-windows-7-automatically-changes-reference-to-syswow64-mscom).
As a workaround, I now added another button to the form. So after selecting the node in the tree, the user now has to additionally click the button. Not so shiny, but at least it works.

Comment: No problem. I've actually had a lot of grief with MSCOMCTL myself, as every time it is patched it tends to break any apps using ListViews (though not TreeViews in my experience). One option I've played around with (but not fully implemented due to switching to .NET) is referencing a separate copy of MSCOMCTL, not stored in System32, but elsewhere on the C drive. It seemed to fix my issues (though I had concerns about missing out on security updates) and wonder if it might help in this situation?